# BASH: How to call and assign one of the data to a variable from text list file

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

file text.txt:

```
11
22
```

test.sh file:

```
#!bin/bash

mapfile -t data < text.txt

firstVal = printf '%s' "${data[0]}"

printf '%s' $firstVal

exit 0
```

error:
`test.sh: line 5: firstVal: command not found`

Question:
What is the right expression for assigning the data of array to a variable? I've tried using $() too, but same result.

Comment: You'd have the same problem with *every* assignment when adding spaces around the `=` (making the operation no longer an assignment at all); it has nothing to do with arrays or text files. (In addition to the linked duplicate, please paste your code into http://shellcheck.net/ and follow the links in its analysis).

Comment: `firstVal=${data[0]}`, also hard coding an explicit exit status is not a good idea since your script might exit with another value than `0`, just let the script exit with the last command executed but that's just me.